# Using Salesforce DX with B2B Commerce (CloudCraze)

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

we are about to work on B2B Commerce (CloudCraze) and are looking into the possibility of using the Salesforce CLI for CI/CD.

Can anyone tell me, if this is generally possible and if there are any caveats?

Thanks a bunch!

Jörn

Comment: Have you tried creating a scratch org with B2B Commerce enabled? I'd assume that as long as you have community licenses added, and move the configuration values it should work just the same as regular managed packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use scratch orgs with B2B Commerce Cloud, because a B2B Commerce Cloud org requires a permission set license to be installed. 
You can, however, use SFDX CLI: instead of force:source:push and force:source:pull, which transfer code to and from a scratch org, you can use force:source:deploy and force:source:retrieve, respectively.

You can use VisualStudio Code with the Salesforce extensions as explained here:
https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/user-guide/org-development-model

This video may also be helpful (noteworthy references to the above from 13:36 onwards):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hw9LBvjo4PQ&feature=youtu.be